# How to use the definition of differentiability in higher dimensions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Lets work on an example to illustrate the problem. Let $g(x,y)$ be defined as:
$$
 g(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2},  & \text{if $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$} \\
0, & \text{if $(x,y) = 0$}
\end{cases}
$$

I want to know, using the definition of differentiability, if $g(x,y)$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$. So first lets compute the partial derivatives at $(0,0)$.
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(0,0) =\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{g(h,0)-g(0,0)}{h}=\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\frac{h^3}{h^2}-0}{h}=1
$$
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(0,0) =\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{g(0,h)-g(0,0)}{h}=\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\frac{h^3}{h^2}-0}{h}=1
$$
So T is the linear transformation defined as:
$$
T:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}
$$
$$
(x,y) \to x+y
$$

Now we need to apply the definition:
$$
\lim_{||(x,y)|| \to 0} \frac{||g(x,y)-g(0,0)-T(x,y)||}{||(x,y)||}=0
$$
$$
\lim_{||(x,y)|| \to 0}=\frac{||\frac{x^3+y^3}{x^2+y^2}-0-x-y||}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
$$
So, how to apply this transformation? How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Write this limit in more detail as the first step (e.g., $g(0,0)=0$, etc).

Comment: Is the limit I wrote correct?

Comment: Yes, can you do more work on the numerator? For instance, can you add fractions? Can you get rid of the vertical bars?

Comment: Important fine point: *IF* $g$ is differentiable, then its differential must be $T$ because of the values that you’ve computed for $g_x$ and $g_y$. Try converting the expression that you’ve derived into polar coordinates.

Comment: But how do I eliminate the vertical bars?

Answer (score 1):

In the numerator, you have the norm of a real number, so it's just the absolute value.  That is, you can replace the double vertical bars by single vertical bars.  Then you can add the fractions and simplify, and what you want to show is $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\mid xy(x+y)\mid}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0
$$

We know $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}|xy|=0,$ so the problem is to deal with $$h(x,y)=\frac{\mid x+y\mid}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$ It would be enough to show that $h$ is bounded near $(0,0),$ because then $|xy|h(x,y)$ would go to zero.

One way to show this is to convert to polar coordinates, as another answer suggested.  Alternatively, you can square $h,$ to get rid of the pesky square root, and show that $h^2$ is bounded.  Now,
$$h^2(x,y)=\frac{\mid x+y\mid^2}{x^2+y^2}\le
\frac{(|x|+|y|)^2}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{x^2+y^2+2|xy|}{x^2+y^2}=1+\frac{2|xy|}{x^2+y^2}     
$$
So, to finish this off, you just need to show that $$\frac{|xy|}{x^2+y^2}$$  is bounded, if $(x,y)\ne(0,0),$ and this is easy. If $|x|\ge|y|$ then $$\frac{|xy|}{x^2+y^2}\le \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}\le1
$$ and similarly if $|y|\ge|x|.$

Answer (score 0):

switching to polar coordinates, you can see that a radius-dependant term (that goes to 0 as (x,y) goes to 0) is multiplied by sin(theta)/cos(theta)-term which is bounded, therefore the whole expression goes to zero.

then again, you could use that without proving differentiability by definition in the first place so there might be a more "appropriate" way to show it